# How do I set the CSS for one instance of a class when the markup has multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page with a content accordion with 8 items. I also have an `h4` tag on the page outside of the accordion. I want to hide which ever content accordion item matches the text inside the `h4` tag.

The text inside the `h4` tag and the content accordion items might change so I need to use variables (I think).

Here is what I have so far:

```
var category = $('.leftColumnNav h4').html();
var topic = $('.contentAccordionItemTitle p').html();

if(topic === category){
  $(".contentAccordionItemTitle").css("display", "none");
} else {
  $(".contentAccordionItemTitle").css("display", "block");
}
```

What I have sort of works. It successfully hides the `.contentAccordionItemTitle`. Unfortunately it obviously hides all of them. I just want to hide the one that matches the `h4` tag.

If it's needed I can probably create a JSFiddle example.

Comment: Can you show your Html markup..?

Comment: "If it's needed I can probably create a JSFiddle example." It's usually a good idea to include a jsFiddle with questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var category = $('.leftColumnNav h4').text();

$(".contentAccordionItemTitle").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() === category) { $(this).hide() }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var topic = $('.contentAccordionItemTitle p').html();
```

That line means you're getting all the p-tags. If you want to continue down this solution, you could use the jQuery each function -> http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
      $(".contentAccordionItemTitle").css("display", "none");
  } else {
      $(".contentAccordionItemTitle").css("display", "block");
```

The `$(".contentAccordionItemTitle")` also gets all elements with this class.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a loop, like jQuery each:

```
var category = jQuery('.leftColumnNav h4').html();
jQuery('.contentAccordionItemTitle p').each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).html() === category) {
        jQuery(this).parent('.contentAccordionItemTitle').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).parent('.contentAccordionItemTitle').css('display', 'block');
    }
```

This is assuming there is only one element that matches `jQuery('.leftColumnNav h4')`